# Error in Integrate zxing barcode scanner into your Android app natively using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, zxing

I am following what is done in this tutorial ([Integrate zxing barcode scanner into your Android app natively using Eclipse](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) ) step by step, but the library projhect has more that one error .. such as in `Android_Manifest.xml` file in the code :

```
 <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="true"
                    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

I get the error :

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'
```

where the androi build target is `android 2.2`

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set the "target=" version in project.properties to a more advanced version, even if your target is 2.2 - extra large screens were introduced in 2.3, if I remember correctly.